# How to bind values to ul on dropdown selectedindexchange using knockout.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I'm struggling with Knockout JS. In my web page, after page loaded event ul showing some list of values from database successfully. Below is the code

```
         <ul data-role="listview" data-divider-theme="b" data-inset="true" data-bind="foreach: Cs">

       <li data-theme="c">
              <a href="#page1" data-transition="slide" data-bind="attr: { title: CID }">
                  <span data-bind="text: FName + ' ' + LName +')'"></span>
              </a>
          </li>

      </ul>

function SSSmodel() {
    var self = this;
   self.Cs = $.parseJSON(localStorage["CsTab"]);       
};
```

Onchange event of dropdown binding new list to that ul. But its not binding new values. Ul showing old values.
below is the onchage function of dropdown.

```
      function onchange()
        {
      //b contain array of elements
       localStorage["aa"] = b;//i checked b.it contains array of values
      ko.applyBindings(new SSSmodel());  
       }
       function SSSmodel() {
    var self = this;

    self.Contacts = $.parseJSON(localStorage["aa"]);
};
 }
```

it doesn't show any error and also not binding new values to ul. Why? 
Please tell me where i made mistake and give tips to solve this problem.

Comment: Could you make a fiddle that reproduce the problem ?

Comment: i think you have to call it on 'onLoad' event.

Comment: Hi mota, onLoad event is called for dropdown or what? I want to bind the new list of datas to ul when onSelectedIndexChanged of dropdown happened

Comment: check updated link, i bind the value on index change of dropdown.in your case data will be dynamic. but i took a fixed collection of data.

Comment: Sorry motta, its also not working..My dropdown already had values. I want to bind new list. In my webpage already contain three dropdowns..

Comment: when you want to bind values, 1) onLoad complete of webpage, or 2)on change value of dropdown.

Comment: Hi motta, on change value of dropdown. Onchange event is calling successfully using knockout.js. but i don't know how to bind values to ul?Please help me friend.

Comment: I rolled the question back to repair someone's delete edit. Deleting all the code out of someone's question is rude.  Please don't do that.  If someone does it to you, it is easy to fix:  click edit, and use a rollback link.  Don't do it back to them, they just want attention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try as like this:

```
 self.Contacts = ko.observable($.parseJSON(localStorage["ContactsTable"]));
```

Answer (score 0):

**Updated :**
It seems you have used a reserved keyword `onchange` for function name. Change it with any other name like `onValueChange` and it will work.

> call the function from somewhere in your code. here is [Working Sample](http://jsfiddle.net/84SUf/1/)

```
 onchange1();
    function onchange1() {
        //b contain array of elements
        //    localStorage["aa"] = b; //i checked b.it contains array of values
        ko.applyBindings(new StrikeAppSearchViewModel());
    }
    function StrikeAppSearchViewModel() {
        var self = this;

        self.Contacts = [
        { ContactID: "MyId1", FirstName: "Jhon", LastName: "Singh dfhd" },
        { ContactID: "MyId2", FirstName: "Dick", LastName: "YBJ" },
        { ContactID: "MyId3", FirstName: "Harry", LastName: "Pdafhd"}];
    };
```

Comment: Sorry Mota, I changed also. but i didn't work. Really I don't know how to bind values to ul while onChange event is fired? Please help me

Comment: Sorry mota. above is not working for me. I want bind the data to ul when selectedindexchanged event of dropdown is called.

Comment: where is dropdown in your code, plz paste your full code.I will help you out.

Comment: @Giri Please don't try to edit answers and delete code or replace the code with a fiddle link.  A jsfiddle link is not a substitute for code, SO wants the code.  If code is in error, comment to the author, they may try to fix it and learn from the experience.

Answer (score 0):

For this scenario, You have to made Jquery Ajax call , then only it will retrieve data are bind to UL.

```
  function StrikeAppViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.Contacts = ko.observableArray();
    self.Contacts = ko.observable($.parseJSON(localStorage["ContactsTable"]));

    self.SearchContacts = function () {

        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://localhost:12345/api/Contact',
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            data: { ID: id },
            context: this,
            success: function (result) {
                debugger;
                self.Contacts(result);

            },
            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {

                alert(errorThrown);
            }
        });

    }


};
```